# Rails 4 - helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I'm trying to figure out how to use a helper method I've written.

It works fine in the profile model, however it isn't working as i want it to in the user model.

I have models called user and role. They are associated as has and belongs to many.

In my role helper, I have:

module RolesHelper

```
def text_for_role(name)
  case name
      when 'guest'
        'Guest Pass'
  end
end
```

In my user index show page I have:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>


              <%= user.roles.each do |role| %>
                <%= text_for_role(role.name)%>
              <% end %>                   
          </td>
```

When I try this, it renders:

Guest Pass [#]

How do i get rid of the bit inside the []? - I only want to show the role name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<%= user.roles.each do |role| %>
```

To

```
<% user.roles.each do |role| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
module RolesHelper
  @roles = {
    'Guest' => 'Guest Pass',
    'Admin' => 'Admin pass',
  }

class << self
  def list
    @roles.map{|k,v| [k,v] }
  end

  def role(str)
    return @roles[str]
  end
end
end
```

**Index page:**

```
<%= user.roles.each do |role| %>
      <% RolesHelper.role(role)%>
<% end %>
```

Also if you do in **users_controller.rb**, that would load roles faster for each user.

```
def index
    @users = User.includes(:role)
end
```